# Census India, population by religion - village (ward) level

Tags: census, india, religion

What I am looking for is the religious composition on a village/ward level from the census.
The official census doesn't seem to report it, but since it is available for [towns](http://www.censusindia.gov.in/2011census/C-01.html) and the census abstract (including literacy rates etc.) is available on a [village level](http://censusindia.gov.in/pca/pcadata/pca.html) I still hope that it might be available somewhere.
I actually don't care from which census, even pretty old ones would be OK (even off-census estimates). The only thing on religion I could find from the 2001 census was [aggregates per state](http://censusindia.gov.in/Census_Data_2001/Census_data_finder/C_Series/Population_by_religious_communities.htm).